# Character Counter Program

Tags: c#, arraylist, casting, char, ascii

I am trying to create a program that counts ASCII characters in a file and keeps track of how many times each character appears in the file. It then should write the output to a file. If the file just read "Hello" the output file should be formatted to show:

H(72) 1
e(101) 1
l(108) 2
o(111) 1
.(46) 1

The code I have written so far is below:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections;

class CharacterFrequency
{
    char ch;
    int frequency;
    public char getCharacter()
    {
        return ch;
    }
    public void setCharacter(char ch)
    {
        this.ch = ch;
    }
    public int getfrequency()
    {
        return frequency;
    }
    public void setfrequency(int frequency)
    {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }


    static void Main()
    {
        string OutputFileName;
        string InputFileName;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the file path");
        InputFileName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the outputfile name");
        OutputFileName = Console.ReadLine();
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(OutputFileName);

        string data = File.ReadAllText(InputFileName);

        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al.Add(data);
        //create two for loops to traverse through the arraylist and compare
        for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
        {
            //create variable k to count the repeated element
            //(if k>0 it means that the particular element is not the first instance)
            int k = 0;
            //count frequency variable
            int f = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < al.Count; j++)
            {
                //compare the characters
                if (al[i].Equals(al[j]))
                {
                    f++;
                    if (i > j) { k++; }
                }
            }
            if (k == 0)
            {
                //Display in the correct format
                Console.Write(al[i] + "(" + (int)al[i] + ")" + f + " ");
            }

        }



    }
}
```

I get an error on the last line of code (Console.Write) which states: "Specified cast is not valid." I know this program may not be written correctly, but I am having a hard time trying to accomplish this task using an array list. I have accomplished this task using a Sorted Dictionary in a previous program but I now have to use an Array List. Any advice about how to fix the error and how my program looks is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using ArrayList? Use a `List<T>` instead

Comment: You can't cast a char to an int that way. Try using GetNumericValue instead.

Comment: You don't even need to do that, just remove the "(int)" from the Console.WriteLine() that fixes the error but you still have to finish writing the code to count chars

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it pretty similar I was able to get this to run. If you keep it as a string and treat it as a char array it works pretty good.

```
 string data = "Hello";
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        int k = 0;
        int f = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
        {      
            if (data[i].Equals(data[j]))
            {
                f++;
                if (i > j) { k++; }
            }
        }

            //Display in the correct format
            Console.Write(data[i] + "(" + (int)data[i] + ")" + f + " ");
    }
```